Wilcoxon signed rank test in QI macros
I need some help in understanding the wilcoxon signed rank test. I am using this test on comparing two analysers. We ran the same samples on two analysers for the PT (prothrombin time), the results were non parametric. I ran the wilcoxon signed rank test on the QI macro application and the column that works out the difference between the data sets (each point) shows the difference as being 1 or less than 1 on all data points. However the test still rejects the null hypothesis that the data between the two data sets is not different.
When comparing another test, the differences are less than 0.1.
In another data set (again non-parametric), the test was able to reject the null hypothesis even though the differences between the data sets are >1.
Would someone be able to explain why this would be? Am I using the incorrect test?

"Results" and "data" cannot be parametric or non-parametric. Those are characteristics of models, not data.

What about these results confuses you?  (Also, in your second paragraph, do you mean "unable" rather than "able"? That would make a bit more sense in context).
